# PHP: php can't find a class defined in an include() script

Tags: php, class, include

I am trying to use Michelf's PHP implementation of Markdown.

I'm including his Markdown.php script with include() at the beginning of my main script, but when trying to use the class (be it for creating a new object or using a method directly), I get this:

Fatal error: Class 'Markdown' not found in [my main script]

The class Markdown is cleary defined in included Markdown.php however.

I've checked, of course, that the include works. I've tried placing Markdown.php in both my include_path and my main script's path, it doesn't change anything.

I am at a loss.

Comment: Look at `markdown.php` does it start with `class Markdown {` or `function markdown`

Comment: @DarylGill It's a namespaced class.

Comment: @Jack Indeed. That was the piece I missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the [source file](https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown/blob/lib/Michelf/Markdown.php#L13), you most likely forgot to [import](http://sg3.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) the class before using it:

```php
use Michelf\Markdown;

// ...

$md = new Markdown();
```

Alternatively, you could use the canonical name:

```
$md = new \Michelf\Markdown();
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know anything about namespaces. After you pointed it out I went to educate myself a bit, and now it works.